# pthread_rwlock_rdlock не блокирует доступ

Tags: c, pthread, mutex

В нижеприведенном коде возникает следующая проблема:
pthread_rwlock_rdlock не блокирует ресурс. То есть поток под номером 3 не ожидает разблокировки после блокирования ресурса, а повторно блокирует и разблокирует pthread_rwlock_t RDrwlock (прошу прощения за некорректную формулировку, не знаю как правильно выразиться); но поток под номером 4 отрабатывает корректно, т.е. ожидает разблокировки ресурса, после сам блокирует ресурс и разблокирует(код практически идентичен, отличие лишь в том что делаем wrlock, а не rdlock). после вызова pthread_rwlock_rdlock() в main() и в void* thread_rdlock(void *args) флаг выставлеются в SUCCESS. компилирую так gcc main.c -lpthread. Вывод программы следующий:

Start thread of rw_lock
Start thread of spin_lock
Start thread of rd_lock
Thread RDlock lock //проблема  с этим потоком
Thread RDlock unlock //проблема  с этим потоком
Thread canceled. 3 //проблема  с этим потоком
Start thread of mutex

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define FNAME "/tmp/main.pid"

typedef struct mutex_int{
    int number_thread;
    pthread_mutex_t *pmutex;
} mutex_int;

typedef struct rwlock_int{
    int number_thread;
    pthread_rwlock_t *prwlock;
} rwlock_int;

typedef struct spin_int{
    int number_thread;
    pthread_spinlock_t *pspinlock;
} spin_int;

void write_pid(){
    FILE* f = fopen(FNAME, "w");
    if(f==NULL){
        perror( "Error open: ");
        exit(1);
    }
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    int wr = fwrite(&pid,sizeof(pid_t),1,f);//write of int!!!
    if (wr==0){
        perror("Error write: ");
        exit(2);
    }
    fflush(f);
    fclose(f);
}

void ret_func_thread(void *arg){
    printf("\nThread canceled. %d\n", *((int *) arg));
}

void* thread_mutex(void *args){
    printf("Start thread of mutex\n");
    struct mutex_int *pmutex_int = (struct mutex_int *) args;
    pthread_cleanup_push(ret_func_thread, &(pmutex_int->number_thread));
    pthread_mutex_lock(pmutex_int->pmutex);
    printf("Thread mutex lock\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(pmutex_int->pmutex);
    printf("Thread mutex unlock\n");
    pthread_cleanup_pop(1);
    return NULL;
}

void* thread_spin(void *args){
    printf("Start thread of spin_lock\n");
    struct spin_int *pspin_int = (struct spin_int *) args;
    pthread_cleanup_push(ret_func_thread, &(pspin_int->number_thread));
    pthread_spin_lock(pspin_int->pspinlock);
    printf("Thread spin lock\n");
    pthread_spin_unlock(pspin_int->pspinlock);
    printf("Thread spin unlock\n");
    pthread_cleanup_pop(1);
    return NULL;
}

void* thread_rdlock(void *args){
    printf("Start thread of rd_lock\n");
    struct rwlock_int *prwlock_int = (struct rwlock_int *) args;
    pthread_cleanup_push(ret_func_thread, &(prwlock_int->number_thread));
    pthread_rwlock_rdlock(prwlock_int->prwlock);
    perror("Err: ");
    printf("Thread RDlock lock\n");
    pthread_rwlock_unlock(prwlock_int->prwlock);
    printf("Thread RDlock unlock\n");
    pthread_cleanup_pop(1);
    return NULL;
}
void* thread_wrlock(void *args){
    printf("Start thread of rw_lock\n");
    struct rwlock_int *prwlock_int = (struct rwlock_int *) args;
    pthread_cleanup_push(ret_func_thread, &(prwlock_int->number_thread));
    pthread_rwlock_wrlock(prwlock_int->prwlock);
    printf("Thread WRlock lock\n");
    pthread_rwlock_unlock(prwlock_int->prwlock);
    printf("Thread WRlock unlock\n");
    pthread_cleanup_pop(1);
    return NULL;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv){
    write_pid();
    pthread_t threads[4];
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    //init
    pthread_spinlock_t spinlock;
    pthread_rwlock_t WRrwlock;
    pthread_rwlock_t RDrwlock;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    pthread_spin_init(&spinlock, PTHREAD_PROCESS_PRIVATE);
    pthread_spin_lock(&spinlock );
    pthread_rwlock_init(&WRrwlock, PTHREAD_PROCESS_PRIVATE);
    pthread_rwlock_init(&RDrwlock, PTHREAD_PROCESS_PRIVATE);
    pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&RDrwlock);
    pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&WRrwlock);
    //create thread
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    struct mutex_int args0;
    args0.number_thread = 1;
    args0.pmutex = &mutex;
    pthread_create(&threads[0],&attr,thread_mutex,&args0);
    struct spin_int args1;
    args1.number_thread = 2;
    args1.pspinlock = &spinlock;
    pthread_create(&threads[1],&attr,thread_spin,&args1);
    struct rwlock_int args2;
    args2.number_thread = 3;
    args2.prwlock = &RDrwlock;
    pthread_create(&threads[2],&attr,thread_rdlock,&args2);
    struct rwlock_int args3;
    args3.number_thread = 4;
    args3.prwlock = &WRrwlock;
    pthread_create(&threads[3],&attr,thread_wrlock,&args3);
    //create sigset
    sigset_t sigset;
    sigemptyset(&sigset);
    sigaddset(&sigset, SIGTERM);
    sigaddset(&sigset, SIGINT);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,&sigset, NULL);
    //wait of signal in sigset. ret signal in sig
    int sig;
    sigwait(&sigset,&sig);
    printf("%d",sig);
    //unlock
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_spin_unlock(&spinlock);
    pthread_rwlock_unlock(&RDrwlock);
    pthread_rwlock_unlock(&WRrwlock);
    //join thread
    pthread_join(threads[0],NULL);
    pthread_join(threads[1],NULL);
    pthread_join(threads[2],NULL);
    pthread_join(threads[3],NULL);
    //destroy mutex
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    pthread_spin_destroy(&spinlock);
    pthread_rwlock_destroy(&RDrwlock);
    pthread_rwlock_destroy(&WRrwlock);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конечном итоге разобрался сам. При блокировке на чтение происходит Shared блокировка. Т.е. несколько читателей могут блокировать ресурс одновременно(число читателей увеличивается при блокировке и уменьшается при unlock(могу ошибиться но вроде как имеется счётчик блокировки ресурса на чтение). При этом писатель не получит доступ пока все читатели не сделают unlock. А в случае писателя происходит блокировка только 1 раз, все остальные будут ждать когда он разблокирует ресурс. Решение найдено в man pthread_rwlock_rdlock, и экспериментальным путем.